# Why doesn't xsetwacom work from udev?

Tags: xorg, devices, udev

I made a script to rotate my Wacom Bamboo tablet 180 degrees. It works fine when I execute it as myself (user) or root, but when started from `udev` (i.e. when plugging the tablet into a `usb` port) it won't work.

**Udev rules**:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="056a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="00d1", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Wacom Co.,Ltd.", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/red-wacom-bamboo.sh"
```

**Wacom script /usr/local/bin/red-wacom-bamboo.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec > /tmp/red-wacom.log
exec 2>&1

# I had to do this otherwise xsetwacom would say:
# "Failed to open Display ."
# Is there a way to do this without using my username?
export XAUTHORITY=/home/redsandro/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0

/usr/bin/xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen stylus" Rotate half
/usr/bin/xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch" Rotate half
```

**Result in /tmp/red-wacom.log**:

```
Cannot find device 'Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen stylus'.
Cannot find device 'Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch'.
```

(Note that the error in the log means the udev rule itself is not the problem.)

I tried setting a `sleep` in the script, maybe it needs a few ms. But that doesn't help.

- Why doesn't this script work when called directly from `udev`?

  - How do I fix this?
- Can I call a script from `udev` as a specific user? (e.g. sync `/home` to external backup drive - /home/ is only visible to it's user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fairly easy workaround, you can add something like this to your `xorg.conf` (or a file in `xorg.conf.d`, as I've done):

```
anthony@Watt:/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d$ cat 55-local-wacom.conf 
Section "InputClass"
       Identifier "Wacom Left Handed"
       MatchDriver "wacom"
       Option "Rotate" "half"
EndSection
```

Check the [wacom(4) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/4/wacom) for details of all the options you can set.

(In theory, you can use `MatchProduct` to individually configure the touchpad, pen, eraser, etc., but when I tried that a while back, it caused Xorg to segfault. Same if I tried to float them. But you're not doing any of that... and maybe the bug is fixed now.)

Comment: Wow, after so many googling I never came across this. I upvoted your answer. I will try it out when I am at work. Any specific reason for `55`? I always use the idea that  "numberless entries are processed last, so it's best to skip numbers for custom entries."

Comment: @Redsandro `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf` is 50 on my system, so I picked 55 to come after it. Not sure that even matters.

Comment: This answer provides useful information but doesn't answer the original question. What if you plug in your USB Wacom device *after* the X server has started ?

Comment: @Lqueryvg InputClass applies to hotplugged devices, so it should work then too.

Comment: @derobert, thanks for responding. I didn't realise InputClass worked for hotplug too. I have some button events which I map using xsetwacom and  I'd like to trigger them if I hotplug my tablet after X has started. I will give this a try. Thanks !

Comment: Works a treat. Whether the Wacom is plugged in before or after X is started. And saves having a convoluted approach combining xinitrc scripts and udev. No need to use xsetwacom any more. The only (small) downside is that it's not user specific, i.e. the setting applies for all users. But for a single user's PC this is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

It works if you create two files, one wrapper script being called by udev, which in turns calls the actual configuration script in the background. The configuration script needs to sleep for a short while, so that X11 has time to do its job. Here's the setup I use:

**Wrapper script called by udev (/usr/local/bin/setupwacom.sh):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/usr/local/bin/setupwacom-post-X11.sh &
```

**Configuration script called by the wrapper script (/usr/local/bin/setupwacom-post-X11.sh):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sleep 2
export XAUTHORITY=/home/adrian/.Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:0
# Put your xsetwacom commands here, for example: 
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S Pad pad" Button 1 "key +ctrl +shift e"
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here worked for me, and the options I wanted to set could not be specified in `xorg.conf`:

```
$ xsetwacom -x get 'Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad' button 1 
Button: Actions are not supported by xorg.conf. Try shell format (-s) instead.
```

I ended up having to start the script with a systemd service triggered by a udev rule:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-wacom.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="056a", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="0302", TAG+="systemd"
```

Vendor and model id can be found running `lsusb` with the device plugged in.

To reload udev rules:

```
$ udevadm control --reload-rules
$ udevadm trigger
```

The `TAG+="systemd"` enables other systemd services (system or user) to depend on the device (registers it as a device unit, see `man systemd.device`). To find the name of the device unit run `udevadm monitor` and plug in the tablet. I get

```
UDEV  [2918.098423] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3 (usb)
...
```

To check that systemd is picking it up do

```
$ systemctl status /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/
● sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.3.device - CTH-480 [Intuos Pen & Touch (S)]
   Loaded: loaded
   Active: active (plugged) since Mon 2016-06-20 11:14:20 UYT; 29min ago
   Device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3
```

So the device unit is `sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.3.device`, and it can be used in the systemd service unit

```
 $ cat .config/systemd/user/wacom.service    
[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
ExecStart=/path/to/wacom-pad-button-setup

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.1.device
WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.2.device
WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.3.device
```

There is one device unit per usb port.

Then enable and reload the unit with `systemctl --user enable wacom.service` and `systemctl --user daemon-reload`.

The script still needs to sleep a bit for xsetwacom to find the device, and to set `$DISPLAY` and `$XAUTHORITY`. `Type=oneshot` works fine when plugging it in, but it doesn't run it if the device was already plugged in when booting the computer. That is why I needed to use a user service instead of a system one, and why the unit also has `WantedBy=default.target`. The problem with oneshot is that it was blocking startx. `Type=forking` and `Restart=no` tells systemd not to wait for the script's forked process to exit, so the script can then sleep in the background waiting for Xorg to start.

```
$ cat bin/wacom-pad-button-setup
#!/bin/rc
{
    sleep 2

    if (~ $DISPLAY ()) {
        DISPLAY=:0
        XAUTHORITY=/home/spelufo/.Xauthority
    }

    xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad' button 9 'button +3 -3'
    xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad' button 8 'button +4 -4'
    xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad' button 3 'button +1 -1'
    xsetwacom set 'Wacom Intuos PT S Pad pad' button 1 'button +2 -2'
} &
```

Comment: I dont know why it was not the case in your scenario, but I had to escape at least the `\x` to `\\x` in the service file. My WantedBy's looked like this in the end: `WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000\:00-0000\:00\:14.0-usb1-1\\x2d4.device` and now they are triggered... before they didnt.

Answer (score 2):

When you plug in the device:

1. Linux detects the device and creates a device entry based on udev rules.
2. The X server detects the device.

You cannot run `xsetwacom` before stage 2. Your script is failing because you're running it at stage 1, when X doesn't know the device yet.

You can set some settings with [`gnome-settings-daemon`](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/linuxwacom/index.php?title=Tablet_Configuration). I believe it gets its notification of the new device through [D-Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus), but I don't know what the D-Bus event looks like. Try spying on the bus with `dbus-monitor`.

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the details, but I am not sure this is correct for the following reason: I tried using `sleep` with a bunch of seconds. When plugging in, the tablet works after less than a second, so by the time the commands get executed, the device is already detected and in use by `X`. But still it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

The workaround by derobert is not suitable for all situations (if you can't use the xorg.conf).

The proposed wrap and `sleep` solution by Adrian is somehow not working for me (ubuntu 16.04).

If you add this to the top of your xsetwacom script:

```
exec > /tmp/debug-my-script.txt 2>&1
xinput --list
```

You can see from the output that the xsetwacom script is somehow still executed before `xinput` is aware of the wacom. No matter how long you make the sleep.

What I propose here is another solution/workaround using the little program [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) which is simpler than the solution by spelufo (which I didn't try) but only requires to install the `at` program. (`sudo apt install at` for debian users).

Now change your wrapper script (Adrian's answer) to something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
at now -f /usr/local/bin/setupwacom-post-X11.sh
```

`at` is normally used to schedule a command once, you can for example schedule one hour ahead by `at now +1 hours -f yourscript.sh`. But since you can only add minutes/hours/days/weeks I used `now` without addition but rely on the sleep inside the xsetwacom script.

Comment: Faced the same issue with Adrian's suggestion and this fixed it for me on 16.04 Ubuntu. I baffles me how it started working with `at now` without any forking. Any reason for that? Actually with the `at` method it doesn't even need the wrapper script. You can directly add it as `.., RUN+="/usr/bin/at now -f script-path"` :)

Comment: This is so crazy since I didn't even have the sleep in the script and it's working without it. I wish I know what's happening in the background so that it's working with `at`